# Appengine: Best way to read a CSV file into app inventor

Tags: google-app-engine, csv, import

I have a csv file and I'd need to get it into a list object in app inventor.

I'm not sure if there is a better / simpler method, but I've looked at the following methods and I'm not really sure the best route.
Also I'm using python but I could switch to use java app engine.

- [Google Fusion Tables (gft)](http://code.google.com/apis/fusiontables/docs/developers_reference.html)
- [Google Docs & TinyGSdb](http://ai.kittywolf.net/index.php/TinyGSdb)
- [App Engine & Python](http://appinventorapi.com/program-an-api-python/)

Down in the comments there is an example on how to update the app.yaml to include some code to parse a csv file.

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open(‘efile_newestSFO_8354d71d-e3fb-4864-b9bf-5312a89e24d7_2010.csv’,”rU”), delimiter=’,')
for row in reader:
print row[0],row[1]
```

I'd rather not go out to the web every time the app loads to retrieve the list.
Thoughts?

Comment: Do you mean App Inventor, or App Engine?

Comment: well I'd like to use App inventor, but there isn't a block that reads from a csv file. So I'm forced to use the App Engine.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a handler to let you upload the cvs to BlobStore, then use BlobStore APIs from your app to read the file.

That approach is well-described [here](http://ikaisays.com/2010/08/11/using-the-app-engine-mapper-for-bulk-data-import/) (in Java, but the same idea applies to Python).